# Strange bahaviours of the TextView and ListView

Tags: c#, android-layout, xamarin

I am trying to display a recipe that have 3 major components: Header with picture, List of ingredients and the text of method.
When there are a lot of ingredients (ListView) in the list the method text are not shown (TextView). And there is now scroll bar showing.

I've tried I think everything: to make a LinearView, RelativeView, FrameView, StackView, ScrollView. Some of the options does not help, some of them refuse to compile.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <Toolbar
        android:minHeight="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?android:attr/colorPrimary"
        android:minWidth="25px"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/toolbar1">
    </Toolbar>
    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:id="@+id/frameLayout"
        android:layout_below="@id/toolbar1">
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/recipeImageView"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:layout_gravity="top|left"
            android:background="@color/list_image_bg_color"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_noimage" />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/recipeTextTitle"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Title"
            android:textAlignment="viewEnd"
            android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
            android:background="#22000000"
            android:padding="12dp"
            android:textSize="22sp"
            android:gravity="fill_horizontal|center_vertical"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:layout_gravity="right" />
    </FrameLayout>
    <ListView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/textIngredients"
        android:layout_below="@id/frameLayout"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="false" />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Text"
        android:layout_below="@id/textIngredients"
        android:id="@+id/textMethod"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

I need more ideas what I can do. I am totally stack.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if your listview has many items,it will fill the height of the screen,as your textview(method) is defined below the listview ,it would  be outside of the screen,you could not see it.

1.you could define a specific height for the listview so that it does not fill the screen height,then the textview(method) would be visiable

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:orientation="vertical">
  <Toolbar
    android:minHeight="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="?android:attr/colorPrimary"
    android:minWidth="25px"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar1">
  </Toolbar>
  <FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:id="@+id/frameLayout"
    android:layout_below="@id/toolbar1">
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/recipeImageView"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_gravity="top|left"
        android:background="@color/list_image_bg_color"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_noimage" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/recipeTextTitle"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Title"
        android:textAlignment="viewEnd"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
        android:background="#22000000"
        android:padding="12dp"
        android:textSize="22sp"
        android:gravity="fill_horizontal|center_vertical"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_gravity="right" />
  </FrameLayout>
  <ListView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="300dp"
    android:id="@+id/textIngredients"
    android:layout_below="@id/frameLayout"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="false" />
  <TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Text"
    android:layout_below="@id/textIngredients"
    android:id="@+id/textMethod"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

2.define the textview(method) to the bottom of the screen,then put the listview above it.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:orientation="vertical">
  <Toolbar
    android:minHeight="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="?android:attr/colorPrimary"
    android:minWidth="25px"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar1">
  </Toolbar>
  <FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:id="@+id/frameLayout"
    android:layout_below="@id/toolbar1">
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/recipeImageView"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_gravity="top|left"
        android:background="@color/list_image_bg_color"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_noimage" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/recipeTextTitle"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Title"
        android:textAlignment="viewEnd"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
        android:background="#22000000"
        android:padding="12dp"
        android:textSize="22sp"
        android:gravity="fill_horizontal|center_vertical"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_gravity="right" />
  </FrameLayout>
  <TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Text"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:id="@+id/textMethod"/>
  <ListView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/textIngredients"
    android:layout_below="@id/frameLayout"
    android:layout_above="@id/textMethod"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="false" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: That is seems simple solution! Thank you! I'll check it in a week or so, I will be not in front of computer till then.

Comment: I've finally got time to continue my project. Your solution worked (I used both options together). Thank you!